# Render latex equations inside atom

Tags: latex, atom-editor, equation

With atom, hydrogen and jupitor i can view variables and plots inside the editor:
[image]

Is it possible to render out an equation? I know it's possible with sublime:
[image]

But when i try it with hydrogen in atom, it says "No kernel for language latex found
Check that the language for this file is set in Atom and that you have a Jupyter kernel installed for it."

Would love your help.

Comment: Have you tried annotating the cell containing LaTeX with "markdown"? See for example: https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen#multiple-kernels-inside-one-rich-document

Answer (score 0):

Hydrogen runs code with interpreters (called kernels), and can't "run" a LaTeX file (at least until someone writes a compatible [kernel for Jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels)).